# In csgo I got 0-16 does that count as 2 losses?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So today just a few minutes as of 7:03pm we had no wins and the other team had 16 wins at the end so does losing all rounds count as 2 losses?

Comment: why u downvote?!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question here, are the rounds in the same game (ie, two best of five matches) or 16 matches?

Comment: what i mean by 0-16 is in 1 comp match we didn't win 1 single round and the other team won every single round so what I'm asking is since they won every single round in 1 one match does it count as 2 losses.

Comment: No. Even if you lose all 16 rounds in a match. It's only one match!

Comment: so one loss only correct?

Comment: It's only one loss, but in competitive mode a pretty expensive one, since every round counts towards your final score.

Answer (score 3):

It's only 1 loss. A pretty disgraceful loss, but it's still only 1 loss. Just be aware that losing 16-0 will make you de-rank quicker than a 16-14 loss, meaning the bigger the loss the bigger impact on your rank.

Comment: Not entire true. If you carry your team, and have more kills than the enemy and play good, but still loose 16-0 is a much better outcome for you, and you'd loose much less rank, if the game was a 16-14 lost but you didn't have a single kill.

Comment: You are still only just speculating on how the system determines ranks, as of right now, no one knows.

Comment: @Иво Недев that may be true but carrying your team in a 16-0 lose is still worse than carrying your team in a 16-14 lose. No matter which way you look at it a big lose is worse than a close lose.

Answer (score 0):

Getting 16 - 0'd doesn't count as two losses, but if the overall elo of your opponents was lower than yours, your elo could decrease so rapidly that it could be an equivalent of two losses vs. opponents with similar or greater elo.